# mysql - find records where conditions are met in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Table A

```
id, name, address, zip, city
```

Table B

```
id, name, address, zip, city
```

These tables have same structure but contains different data.
I'd like my query to select * from Table B where address, zip and city are equal as in Table A.

Example Adam (from table A) lives at Bigstreet 1, 112233, London.

I want query to return * from Table B with exact same address, zip and city
AND do that for every row in Table A

How do I write such a query. Im kind of out of ideas

Comment: use JOIN ......

Answer (score 0):

You should use a SQL JOIN (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_B 
INNER JOIN table_A
ON table_B.address = table_A.address
AND
ON table_B.zip = table_A.zip
AND
ON table_B.city= table_A.city;
```

Comment: You do not need to use `INNER` nor the second or third `ON` 's.  You can use instead `JOIN table_A ON table_B.address = table_A.address AND table_B.zip = table_A.zip AND table_B.city= table_A.city;`